# Wrapping parts of boost::asio in a C library - for use on embedded Linux

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I'm looking for a good ( and simple ) sockets library that I can incorporate into an XMPP client I am building in C for embedded Linux.

Lots of people have recommended boost::asio, and since I am already familiar with C++ and some aspects of boost - I thought I might wrap this up into a C library to be called from my code.

How difficult to people think this might be as opposed to using another sockets library - am I just overcomplicating things?

I have looked at Simple Sockets Library (written in C) but I find it a bit tricky for asynchronous messages.

Further clarification on the interface I need to support (to answer comment below):
connect(ip, port)

close()

getIncomingMessage()

I also need some way of being notified when something has been sent down the wire - polling would be too intensive as this is for a connection that only gets data sent down it periodically and is ideally open for a long time ( until someone turns off the device ).

Comment: What sort of C interface does your library need to expose?

Comment: If you're only using synchronous io operations, Simple Sockets Library is probably good enough. For asynchronous operations, ASIO is a champ. I'd figure out how you are going to structure your library and your a required `io_service` before worrying about anything else, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Boost ASIO to implement a C interface does sound a bit complicated and mismatched.  How about starting with something more native to C, like [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/)?  I know it's not the same, but it's a start, and socket programming is well supported in C itself.